sqlcmd Login failed for user
I just setup a SQL Server Express instance a Windows PC, added a couple SQL user logins, a database, a linked database, and a stored procedure. I can login via SSMS (on the same computer) with the SQL user creds, connect to the linked database, and run the local stored procedure. No problem.
Now I want to run a sqlcmd command to run the stored procedure, but it keeps failing on the login. Again, doing this on the same PC.
sqlcmd -S TH-DBREP01\sqlexpress -U Guy_RW -P 'TH555!@#'
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login failed for user 'Guy_RW'..
I've been working on this for a couple hours but no luck.

I've been working on this for a couple hours definitely means that other credentials have been tried.

Yes. Have tried 2 other SQL login users.

Once I removed the single quotes from the password, it worked.
